# Do I still lose reputation for downsvoting an answer which is then deleted

Tags: support

Someone posted a [spam answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34769324/how-do-i-add-default-entity-framework-columns-to-my-existing-database/34769374#34769374) to one of my questions I asked today. I flagged the answer and downvoted it to draw attention to the fact it was spam.

The answer was then deleted I suspect because of the flagging.

Do I still lost 1 reputation for down voting an answer even though the answer was deleted?

**PS.** Sorry for double question but is there a way I can flag a User as being a spam user as he is continually posting crap on my question?

Comment: Look at your reputation history in your profile and find out.

Comment: @Servy I removed my downvote after the answer was deleted as I was unsure of what would happen

Comment: @user1, last time I checked you could not remove a downvote on a deleted post.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Huh? Usually the -1 should be restored if the answer was deleted.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That has nothing to do with Fred's comment.

Comment: @πάντα, yup, that's not what I meant. Since the questioner said *I removed my downvote after the answer was deleted*, I was pointing out that they could not do that (since the vote arrows are neutered in deleted posts).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Ah got it now. So may be we should blame caching :-) ...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Maybe I am confusing "deleted" with questions which have been "Faded" because they have got a lot of downvotes

Comment: @user1 _"... but is there a way I can flag a User as being a spam user as he is continually posting crap on my question?"_ You cannot flag users (profiles), but if you are sure that needs mod assistance, flag the question and explain. The mods will see deleted answers, comments and everything needed to investigate and justify.

Comment: An answer fading away means it has several downvotes and is on its way to deletion, but is not deleted yet. When it's deleted it will be only visible to 10k+ users, you won't see it anymore and will gain your rep back.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks for the explanation. I will do that in future if I identify a Spam account

Comment: @EricD. An answer having downvotes is *in no way* meaning that it's on its way to deletion.  It only means that it has downvotes.  Most downvoted posts are never deleted.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You should not be submitting custom mod flag for spam.  You should only ever be submitting spam flags.  The mods will investigate posts flagged as spam appropriately.

Comment: @BillWoodger They never lead to deletion.

Comment: @Servy Good point. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Servy Just to clarify you would advise against πάνταῥεῖ's advise and say to carry on flagging the User's posts as spam?

Comment: @servy Ah, you're right. Bad choice of words from me, I should have said "is *probably* on the road...". Obviously if the answer then gets upvotes it won't be deleted, and all downvoted answers aren't deleted either. This comment just reflected my own experience, which is just that (probably because most of the answers I've downvoted have been deleted).

Comment: @user1 Yes, and I have changed my mind. It would be the better action.

Comment: @EricD. No, there is no need for the answer to get upvotes to "not be deleted".  Answers are never deleted in the first place as a result of downvotes.  And as I said, the vast majority of downvoted answers aren't deleted by the system.  A lot are deleted by the author, but a very tiny fraction are ever deleted by the system.

Comment: @Servy I've explained myself very poorly, I apologize for that. I just wanted to share my experience that "fading away" answers are often on their way to be deleted. That is what I've seen, but I understand it's not a rule, and that it may even be contrary to what other users are experiencing. Sorry, I realize I wasn't clear at all in my previous comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, if an answer you downvoted on is deleted, you will regain your +1 rep.

I often see little +1's in my notifications, and that's what that is.

Comment: Does that still hold if the answer is at score 3+ and age 3+ months at time of deletion?

Comment: Yes. Ever seen rep removed due to "user being removed"? Time is not a factor.

Comment: User being removed is a special case. And that's more that user's votes...